# Tooltwist Designer Repository Sync is failing

Tags: tooltwist

When I sync from the ToolTwist Designer, I select the files I wish to publish, but I get an error when I press OK, saying that the sync failed and to look in the server log file.

If I try again, the files I selected are no longer in the list, but if I check Git I can see they are not pushed to the repository.

In the log file I see that the push failed, and if I go to the webdesign directory and test the push command I get the same error:

```
$ git push --dry-run
To git@github.com:MyRepository/design-project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

I'm using the 'design' branch, so I'm not sure why an error is occurring on the 'master' branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal circumstances the Designer only uses a single git branch, normally named 'design'. The error message above indicates a conflict on the master branch.

It appears that changes have been committed to the master branch on the local machine but not pushed, whilst elsewhere changes have been committed to the master branch and *have* been pushed onto the remote repo.

To clear this conflict you'll need to checkout the master branch and do a pull to merge in the changes on the remote, and then the next push will work. *Don't forget to change back to the design branch when you're finished.*

```
[stop the Designer]
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
[resolve any conflicts]
$ git push origin master

$ git checkout design
[start the Designer]
```

By default git tries to push commits on all branches. In this case, you might find that the conflict on the master branch is preventing your web design changes on the design branch from being committed. To prevent this from happening, you can configure git's default behaviour to only push the current branch.

```
$ git config push.default current
```

You might also want to investigate why the master branch is being changed (and in two locations).